# fastapi + sqlalchemy + pydantic → how to process relations

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Using FastAPI I can't fetch all the data. For example I have this output :

Response body Download (but the items list is always empty):

```py
[
    {
         "email": "mmm@gmail.com",
         "id": 1,
         "is_active": true,
         "items": []
    },
    {
         "email": "ee@gmail.com",
         "id": 2,
         "is_active": true,
         "items": []
    },
]
```

Endpoint are for example:

```py
@app.get("/users/", response_model=list[schemas.User])
async def read_users(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    users = crud.get_users(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return users

@app.get("/users/{user_id}", response_model=schemas.User)
async def read_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user(db, user_id=user_id)
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    return db_user
```

I have the following schemas (database is PostgreSQL):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ItemBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str | None = None

class ItemCreate(ItemBase):
    pass

class Item(ItemBase):
    id: int
    owner: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str

class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str

class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    is_active: bool
    items: list[Item] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Database is postgresql

Models are (table users and table items):

```py
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'socialcampaigns'}


    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    items_rel = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner_id_rel")   

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'socialcampaigns'}
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("socialcampaigns.users.id"))

    owner_id_rel = relationship("User",  back_populates="items_rel")
```

Crud code is:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import models, schemas

def get_user(db: Session, user_id: int):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()

def get_users (db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.User).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

How to solve it? How do I view the list of Items when viewing users?

Comment: Your SQLAlchemy relation is named `items_rel`, but your pydantic relation is named `items` - FastAPI/Pydantic has no way of knowing that you intend these to be the same list of objects unless you tell it so. It's probably better to name your relationship in SQLAlchemy just `items`. I'd also make sure to switch the naming in your Item class - the `owner_id` should refer to the Integer column (since it's the actual integer id), and `owner` should be the resolved owner through `relationship`).